# Multiplayer Flash Game with Java Server problems

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Alright, basically I've been trying to find out how to set up a multiplayer flash game, recently I have concluded to code my own server using Java. I have finally managed to do so after hours of trying and I have bumped into a snag. Here is my server & client code.

Server:

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class ServerFlash
    {   
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
            Socket connection = new Socket();
            InputStream in = null;
            boolean listening = true;

            try
            {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(14804);
                System.err.println("The server is now bound to port.");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Could not bind server to port.");
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            while (listening)
            {
                connection = serverSocket.accept();
                if(connection!=null)
                {
                    System.err.println("Connection to client has been established.");

                    in = connection.getInputStream();
                    listening = false;
                }
            }
            while (!listening)
            {
                int data = in.read();
                if(data!=-1)
                {
                    System.err.println(data);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Client:

```
var server = new Socket();
server.connect("[insertmyip]",14804);

server.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
server.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, onClose);
server.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
server.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onResponse);
server.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecError);

function onConnect(e:Event)
{
    trace("Connection Established.");
}
function onClose(e:Event)
{
    trace("Socket has been Close.");
}
function onError(e:Event)
{
    trace("An Error has occured." + e);
}
function onResponse(e:Event)
{
    trace("Responce has been recieved.");
}
function onSecError(e:Event)
{
    trace("A SecError has occured.");
}
```

When I launch the server everything is okay. However when I launch the client, it successfully connects to the server, but all of a sudden the server receives data from the client (if you read the code the server reads incoming data and displays it) and displays around 15 lines of code and it does not accept any new data from the client. HOWEVER this only happens when the client is launched from a website (or a folder) BUT it works normally when I open the client as a test in Adobe Flash Pro.

If you require files and hand them over.

Comment: What would those '15 lines of code' be?

Comment: 60
112
111
108
105
99
121
45
102
105
108
101
45
114
101
113
117
101
115
116
47
62
0
From the
int data = in.read();
                if(data!=-1)
                {
                    System.err.println(data);
                }
part i think

Comment: And that is `<policy - file-request/ > ` in ASCII.